# Notify certain user when another user adds information to Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making an Uber-style app. I am trying to figure out the best way to send an alert to the driver that he needs to make a collection at a certain location.

I have it set up so that when a user clicks the "collect me" button that it will send the users location coordinates into the Firebase database under the "collections" node.

I want to now notify the driver how that he needs to collect a user that the uploaded coordinates. What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: That's a basic function of Firebase. Leveraging observers that will notify the app when data has been added, changed or removed from Firebase. In your case, when driver starts his app and logs in, his app would be observing the 'collections' node and will be notified if a 'collect me' event is added within his radius. You may want to review the [Getting Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data) guide on the Firebase website and some of the sample apps as it covers this topic pretty well.